# File is not being downloaded on Laravel5 using Response

Tags: httpresponse, laravel-5.1, download, laravel-excel

I use Laravel 5.1.

A jQuery ajax call is made like that:

```
$('#export_selected').click(function(){
                var checked = $('.select_rows:checked');
                var ids     = [];
                $.each(checked, function(index, value){
                    ids.push(value.id);
                })
                $.ajax({
                    method : "POST",
                    url    : "{{URL::to('/spot/exportTable')}}",
                    data   : {ids:ids}
                });
            });
```

And then the php method is defined that way:

```
public function exportTable(Request $req) {
            $spots = array_flatten($req->all());
            $res   = Spot::whereIn('id', $spots)->get();

            Excel::create('Spots', function($excel) use($res) {
                $excel->setTitle('Title goes here');
                $excel->setCreator('Creator Goes Here')->setCompany('Company Goes Here');
                $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use($res) {
                    $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
                    $sheet->fromArray($res);
                });
            })->store('csv', storage_path('/exports', true));

            $file    = base_path() . '/storage/exports/Spots.csv';
            $headers = ['Content-Type: application/csv',  'Content Description: File Transfer', 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'];
            return response()->download($file, 'Spots.csv' , $headers);
    }
```

Chrome developer console prints the results as raw lines.

The file is successfully exported and created in the disk.

The path to file is correct.

But the download is never started.

Echoing the response gives:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
0:                   Content-Type: application/csv
Cache-Control:       public
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Spots.csv"
Date:                Mon, 26 Oct 2015 16:08:26 GMT
Last-Modified:       Mon, 26 Oct 2015 16:08:26 GMT
1:                   Content-Description: File Transfer
2:                   Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

Comment: Delete `$headers` from `response()->download()` and test again

Comment: @manix just did, didn't change a thing. same old result and no download is being initiated. Although I don't think it's a browser problem but I've tried  that on Chrome, Firefox and IE..

Comment: Oh! I get it. You can not  download via ajax. The user must open/download by sending a request and then refrest/redirect the entire browser

Comment: You're right! just tried with a simple form and the download was done with no problem. I will be editing my code to download via Ajax, there is some ways to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the answer here for everybody having the same issue.

@manix figured it out: I'm trying to download via Ajax, which needs to be done in another way, not the way I wrote my code

Comment: how you did it ? can you please explain

Comment: If you want to trigger a download with ajax you have to proceed as [shown in this gist](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743)